# PHP: Check if any values are updated in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create a statement that inserts and updates rows in my database which changes a value in my database when values has changed while updating the row.

I'm not sure if my question is clear enough but here is my code (check the comments, this should clear things up):

```
$stmProducts = $db->prepare("
     INSERT INTO
          products
     SET
          identifier      = :identifier,
          title           = :title,
          price           = :price,
          content         = :content
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
          title           = :title,
          price           = :price,
          content         = :content
          // If any values (title, price or content) has been changed while updating:
          // updated      = true
");
```

I've tried something with `CASE WHEN` but that didn't work, I don't have the exact code I used but it was something like this:

```
updated = CASE WHEN title != :title THEN true END
```

I could be looking into the completely wrong direction but what's the best way to get to what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can know it examining `PDOStatement::rowCount()`. With an insert it will return 1, while with an update will return 2.

Check [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if
>   the row is inserted as a new row, and 2 if an existing row is updated.

Comment: they're using PDO, and not MySQLi

Comment: @AlbertoFernández I just tested it and it seems to work great, thanks!